# Monitor: very low minimum brightness, 4K UHD, 27" (or higher)

Tags: monitors

The monitor is going to be used mostly for office work (programming and browsing) and occasionally for watching a film.

It should have the following properties:

- Very low minimum brightness: Monitors I’ve used so far have had a minimum brightness of around 60 cd/m² (according to the "PRAD" review site), which I found a bit too high when working in an otherwise dark  room.
- no PWM, as it will be used for many hours in a row
- 4K UHD (actually I prefer 16:10, but I know that this is currently hard to get together with the other requirements.)
- I like the 27" size, but I could probably get used to a bigger size.
- height-adjustable
- Ideally, it should have Adaptive-Sync (FreeSync), in case I have a Adaptive-Sync-capable graphics adapter at some point. But at least, it should be possible that it can play 24 Hz content without judder (by setting my graphics adapter output to 24 Hz).

Comment: Would using some kind of software to darken the screen work?

Comment: @CaldeiraG I already use redshift to reduce the amount of blue light during the night. It has an option to reduce overall screen brightness, but that reduces contrast too much.

Comment: I am using the LG 27MU67-B which has all of the features you're looking for, but the lowest brightness setting is *still* too bright for me. Not sure what the actual cd/m^2 value is. Even though software like redshift helps, the actual brightness of the screen does not noticeably dim. (Just easier to look at)

Comment: I think a display technology with emissive pixels like OLED, microLED, QD-LED, etc. may go to a low enough brightness for you.